# LoDash: Get an array of values from an array of object properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm sure it's somewhere inside the LoDash docs, but I can't seem to find the right combination.

```
var users = [{
      id: 12,
      name: 'Adam'
   },{
      id: 14,
      name: 'Bob'
   },{
      id: 16,
      name: 'Charlie'
   },{
      id: 18,
      name: 'David'
   }
]

// how do I get [12, 14, 16, 18]
var userIds = _.map(users, _.pick('id'));
```

Answer (score 415, accepted):

Since version v4.x you should use [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map):

```
_.map(users, 'id'); // [12, 14, 16, 18]
```

this way it is corresponds to native [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method where you would write (ES2015 syntax):

```
users.map(user => user.id); // [12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Before v4.x you could use [`_.pluck`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/doc/README.md#_pluckcollection-path) the same way:

```
_.pluck(users, 'id'); // [12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: thanks much better than ```_.toArray(_.mapValues(users, 'id'))```

Comment: how can i get name with id, I mean how can we fetch more than two values ?

Comment: @John `users.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }))` or less cryptic `users.map(user => ({ id: user.id, name: user.name }))`. Same in lodash: `_.map(users, ({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }))`.

Comment: @dfsq, it's good solution while adding objects into output array. Thanks!

Comment: what if dere is a record multiple times in the original array? how to get unique only

Answer (score 22):

In the new **lodash release v4.0.0** `_.pluck` has removed in favor of `_.map`

Then you can use this:

```
_.map(users, 'id'); // [12, 14, 16, 18]
```

You can see in [Github Changelog](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog)

Answer (score 21):

With pure JS:

```
var userIds = users.map( function(obj) { return obj.id; } );
```

Comment: You can simplify this into var userIds = users.map( obj => obj.id );

Comment: Get on my level `users.map(({id})=>id)`

Answer (score 16):

And if you need to extract several properties from each object, then

```
let newArr = _.map(arr, o => _.pick(o, ['name', 'surname', 'rate']));
```

Comment: Hello, is there any lodash method to achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

Simple and even faster way to get it via ES6

```
let newArray = users.flatMap(i => i.ID) // -> [ 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
```

Comment: Why `flatMap()` instead of `map()`?

Comment: @Lacek `map()` is exist for object manipulation where `flatMap()` just for softing your Array<Object> to single array

Comment: I know the different of `map()` and `flatMap()`. Just wanted to know why you suggested `flatMap()` in this case when there are already answers with `map()`. Would be great if you can elaborate when we should use `flatMap()` instead of `map()`.

Comment: @Lacek Because is really useful in some cases to get basic data that you need from the array. Useful link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Answer (score -3):

If you are using native javascript then you can use this code -

```
let ids = users.map(function(obj, index) {

    return obj.id;
})

console.log(ids); //[12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: The OP explicitly asked for a Lodash solution.

Answer (score -3):

```js
const users = [{
      id: 12,
      name: 'Adam'
   },{
      id: 14,
      name: 'Bob'
   },{
      id: 16,
      name: 'Charlie'
   },{
      id: 18,
      name: 'David'
   }
]
const userIds = _.values(users);
console.log(userIds); //[12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: OP wanted only the ids. Your code does not print out the ids, but the entire objects.

Answer (score -21):

This will give you what you want in a pop-up.

```
for(var i = 0; i < users.Count; i++){
   alert(users[i].id);  
}
```

Comment: It's to loop through the array one element at a time. An array is a data-structure of index(es) with values in it from some data-type (in this example it's objects).  The objects can only be accessed by evaluating the elements in the index of the array. The loop is the structure that achieves this.