# Get the array of values from array of objects using lodash

Tags: arrays, object, lodash

I have this array

```
    this.complementaryFields = [
        {
            fieldName: 'complementaryLaser',
            label: 'Laser Hair Removal'
        },
        {
            fieldName: 'complementarySkin',
            label: 'Skin'
        },
        {
            fieldName: 'complementaryInjection',
            label: 'Cosmetic Injections'
        },
        {
            fieldName: 'complementaryNotSure',
            label: 'Not Sure'
        }
    ];
```

and I would like to create a new array out of it as below:

```
    this.complementaryFieldNames = [
        'complementaryLaser',
        'complementarySkin',
        'complementaryInjection',
        'complementaryNotSure'
    ];
```

How would you do it using lodash?

Comment: Without lodash : `complementaryFieldNames = complementaryFields.map({fieldName} => fieldName)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LoDash: Get an array of values from an array of object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354725/lodash-get-an-array-of-values-from-an-array-of-object-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use lodash [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) to get that result:

```js
const data = [{ fieldName: 'complementaryLaser', label: 'Laser Hair Removal' }, { fieldName: 'complementarySkin', label: 'Skin' }, { fieldName: 'complementaryInjection', label: 'Cosmetic Injections' }, { fieldName: 'complementaryNotSure', label: 'Not Sure' } ];

const result = _.map(data, 'fieldName')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With ES6 you can do same with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and destructuring:

```js
const data = [{ fieldName: 'complementaryLaser', label: 'Laser Hair Removal' }, { fieldName: 'complementarySkin', label: 'Skin' }, { fieldName: 'complementaryInjection', label: 'Cosmetic Injections' }, { fieldName: 'complementaryNotSure', label: 'Not Sure' } ];

const result = data.map(({fieldName}) => fieldName)

console.log(result)
```