# _.map is giving me an error that MAKES NO SENSE

Tags: json, typescript, lodash, angular13

I'm following the following link and it SHOULD work!

[LoDash: Get an array of values from an array of object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354725/lodash-get-an-array-of-values-from-an-array-of-object-properties)

This is the CODE that should work

```
_.map(users, 'id'); // [12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Here's what the example is for the above solution

```
const users = [{
      id: 12,
      name: 'Adam'
   },{
      id: 14,
      name: 'Bob'
   },{
      id: 16,
      name: 'Charlie'
   },{
      id: 18,
      name: 'David'
   }
]
```

Here's my JSON object... it's the entire ZIPCODE, CITY, STATE, COUNTY US Postal Service DB and it's 349,000+ lines of JSON formatted.

This is only a small snippet... and is called: **citystatezip**

```
import * as citystatezip from 'src/assets/json/city-state-zip-county.json';
```

The resulting JSON for the above...

```
[
  {
    "zip_code": 43616,
    "latitude": 41.656948,
    "longitude": -83.44433,
    "city": "Oregon",
    "state": "OH",
    "county": "Lucas"
  },
  {
    "zip_code": 43617,
    "latitude": 41.66765,
    "longitude": -83.722437,
    "city": "Toledo",
    "state": "OH",
    "county": "Lucas"
  },
  {
    "zip_code": 43618,
    "latitude": 41.656948,
    "longitude": -83.399129,
    "city": "Oregon",
    "state": "OH",
    "county": "Lucas"
  }
]
```

all my code is doing is PULLING the JSON object from a file:

```
  getAllZipCodes(): any {
    // this is NOT an error
    this.allzipcodes = _.map(citystatezip, 'zip_code');
  }
```

BUT, the error I'm getting for _.map is in the picture and shown below.

```
import citystatezip
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dictionary<unknown> | NumericDictionary<unknown> | null | undefined'.ts(2769)
collection.d.ts(1180, 9): The last overload is declared here.
```

[image: The error I'm getting with LODASH _.map]

Comment: What's the bundler? Webpack, esbuild, gulp ...?

Comment: WebPack I believe. I'm using ANGULAR 13.x

Comment: This doesn't even work with the citystatezip.map() which is ES6

Comment: It looks like something related to the JSON loader. Or it's missing or it's misconfigured.

Comment: OK, but other LODASH things I'm doing like FOROWN and FILTER and REDUCE are all fine. If there's another WAY for me to get what I need vice LODASH, please suggest with an example.  I just want to make a CITIES ARRAY, COUNTY ARRAY and ZIP CODE ARRAY from the massive JSON I have.

Comment: Does `src/assets/json/city-state-zip-county.json` need to be a JSON? Why not convert it to `.ts` and export the array. You can also force it to be any type with `_.map(citystatezip as unknown as any, 'zip_code');`

Comment: as unknown as any WORKED PERFECTLY! THANK YOU! OMG!